# Pig DateTime Invalid Format error

Tags: datetime, apache-pig, to-date

I am trying to load an input file using Pig

The input data is

```
id,  event_date

894, 10-Sep-2014 02:38:29
```

The event_date is loaded as char array and then it is converted using Pig ToDate function as

```
ToDate(event_date,'dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss')
```

When pig script is run, getting following error message

> Caused by: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Exception while executing [POUserFunc (Name: POUserFunc(org.apache.pig.builtin.ToDate2ARGS)[datetime] - scope-46 Operator Key: scope-46) children: null at []]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "10-Sep-2014 02:38:29" is malformed at " 02:38:29"

Can you please let me know what mistake I have done here ?

Comment: Post your entire script

Comment: I don't see any issues in the command posted. How you are loading the file ? Have you used "," as the delimiter for LOAD ? Can you share the script to look further ?